# Windows Task Scheduler with python -m switch

Tags: python, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a script I am attempting to run via windows task scheduler. I am able to successfully run this in the cmd prompt:

```
>  E:\code\python\Flex-LM-Tool\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m flexlmtool
```

However, when I attempt to set this up in windows task scheduler, I get `(0x1)` result. I have previously run python scripts in task scheduler without an issue, this time however I am passing in 2 arguments. Here is my Actions:

[image: Windows Task Scheduler Actions]

Comment: I'm not sure with python, but with other things that I set up tasks for which run in the cmd, I make the Program/Script cmd.exe and the path to the executable I would run there the argument(s).

Comment: Thanks I tried that but it just hangs and doesn't ever complete the task. I have been able to set the script/program as the python.exe in the past so I don't see why I cannot do it that way again. It would be helpful if windows task scheduler returned more information about why the task failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was running the "-m" switch, I had to set the "start in" option to my module path. Once I did that, everything worked normally.

[image]